How to grow a div to fill space between two other divs?
I have a div at the top of my page (#top) and one set to the bottom of the page with absolute position (#bottom). I have a div in the middle (#middle) with an inner component (#middle-inner). I would like to grow this middle component to fill the entirety of the space between #top and #bottom, without changing the size of the inner content (#middle-inner). The top and bottom divs should not be of fixed height. How can I do this?


<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    height:100%;
}
#top {
    background-color:purple;
}
#middle {
    background-color:green;
}
#middle-inner {
    width: 100px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: red;
}
#bottom {
    background-color:blue;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='top'>
    top
    </div>
    <div id='middle'>
        middle
        <div id='middle-inner'>
            middle inner
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='bottom'>
    bottom
    </div>
</body>
</html>




Using #middle { height: 100vh; } will set the height of the middle to the height of the viewport. However you've got a margin, and a top and bottom div. If you remove the margin: body ( margin: 0; } and set the height of the top and bottom to something fixed, for instance 30px, then you can do: #middle { height: calc(100vh - 60px); }.

@KIKOSoftware thanks however I would rather not set the top and bottom divs to fixed heights as I need their heights to vary

Well the answer by Jacques Rossouw will do that for you. You'll have to deal with the more complicated flex boxes there, but it is worth it and they are in common use.

You achieve this using flex:


<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    html{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }
    body {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #top {
        background-color:purple;
    }
    #middle {
        background-color:green;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #middle-inner {
        width: 100px;
        height:200px;
        background-color: red;
    }
    #bottom {
        background-color:blue;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='top'>
        top
        </div>
        <div id='middle'>
            middle
            <div id='middle-inner'>
                middle inner
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id='bottom'>
        bottom
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>



The basic idea is that you set the html and body css to:
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

This will ensure your content uses the entire size of the window.
Then we can make use of display: flex; to manipulate the structure:
display: flex; -> set display to flex
flex-direction: column; -> content flows down in 1 column (defaults to row)
justify-content: space-between; -> push all the divs to fill the space, which leaves white gaps (will adjust #middle to fix this)

Now adjust #middle to fill the remaining space with height: 100%;.
